# Mapping openNLP or StanfordNLP in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opennlp

I am trying to map openNLP to enable parsing of filed in a document. Using the following code:

```
"article":
"properties":
"content" : { "type" : "opennlp" }
```

Prior to create the mapping, I downloaded the named entity extraction binary file from `sourceforge.net` and installed/unpacked using cURL in `elasticsearch` plugin folders.

I get the following error message when I tried to run the above mapping code.

> "error": "MapperParsingException[No handler for type [opennlp]
>   declared on    field [content]]" "status": 400

Comment: That's an odd installation process for an Elasticsearch plugin.  Can you provide a link to the plugin you installed?

Comment: Here is the link - http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding what an Elasticsearch plugin is, but what you linked is a library and I did not catch anything about how that could be integrated with Elasticsearch.  Take a look at https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-opennlp-plugin which unfortunately seems to only support up to v0.90 but is an example of a plugin bring opennlp and Elasticsearch together.

Answer (score 0):

After quick Googling I've found this: https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-opennlp-plugin

I assume that you're trying to install it. However - it's outdated and probably not even supported by recent Elasticsearch versions.

The purpose of it seems to extract data from files and index them as tags. [Elasticsearch Mapper Attachments Type](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments#mapper-attachments-type-for-elasticsearch) plugin does exactly that. I would encourage you to use it instead of OnenNLP. Quick extract from documentation:

> The mapper attachments plugin adds the attachment type to
>   Elasticsearch using [Apache Tika](http://lucene.apache.org/tika/). The attachment type allows to index
>   different "attachment" type field (encoded as base64), for example,
>   microsoft office formats, open document formats, ePub, HTML, and so on
>   (full list can be found [here](http://tika.apache.org/1.10/formats.html)).

An example how to use map fields using it:

```
PUT /test/person/_mapping
{
  "person" : {
    "properties" : {
      "my_attachment" : {
        "type" : "attachment"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to use the NLP technique to extract the entities(places, organizations, names etc) from the content. The mapper attachment plugin doesn't solve my need. It just defines the mapping to loads the data into the ES.

Comment: Those two plugins are unrelated.  Specifically, the poster seeks to tag content with results of a named entity tagger which elasticsearch-mapper-attachments will not do.